# How does decision tree classifier work for text sentences?

Tags: classification, python, cart, natural-language

[image: a decision tree to classify sentences of either related to sports or crime]

This is an image created using decision tree classifier in which, 30 sentences of two different categories like sports and crime were used. These texts were converted into vectors using `sbert` (each sentence is now represented as integers) and length of each sentence is made to be 112 ( length of short sentences is also made as 112 to make feature every sentence have feature from X0 to X111).

I am trying to figure out how this decision tree works. What do the numbers 345, 196, 5131.5 denote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for your variable 31 (which is your encoded sentence so you have 112 variables)if that value is less than or equal to 345 then you follow the left path that says 'True'.  Else you go right. So basically this variable 31 is the 'best' first split to divide up your data and it found that the variable itself is best split at value 345 for whatever reason.

A decision tree at each split poses a question and the first number you see is that question: is x31 less than or equal to 345.  Then it poses 2 questions with that split:

1. one for the 'Trues'
2. one for the 'Falses'

So the falses get the question is x34 less than or equal to 5131.5? And so on...

All a decision tree does is partition your data and this graph shows you the questions it asks each data point in order to partition it.

For text sentences specifically this process is the same as with anything else.  The only difference is you are using word embeddings or some way to convert the words to numbers that can represent them.  So what does 345 actually mean?  It means nothing except that the vector of all of the variables for a given data point *should* represent a sentence and be closely related to similar sentences. But the numbers mean absolutely nothing on their own, they only mean something relative to other numbers.

Comment: Thanks Tylerr for a detailed answer. Really appreciate it. I tried decoding what that 345 is -- and its showing character P and some other number like 196 is K which as you said does not really mean anything. and 7347 is acquired-  which is not a word in texts that have been inputted..     So are you saying that there is no use in decoding these numbers back into texts, cause we cant figure out on why that number has been selected in this question?     Also you did mention about best split which is 345. So how did the model arrive on that number from the whole list of other number?  i

Comment: For numverical dataset, its easy to figure it out. But with this textual data, its really complicated on what basis these numbers were chosen by the model

Comment: It depends on the exact implementation and I do not know what this embedding is doing but typically you will always lose information going from sentences to a document vector so the numbers themselves won't make sense but what will make sense are the whole vectors relation to similar/dissimilar sentences.  For example: The sentence "I like all kinds of animal except dogs" and "I like all kinds of animals except cats" should be very similar vectors (all 112 ints) except for a few which would be different. So a tree could find one variable to start with which splits between cats and dogs.

Comment: Or it might take several variables for the tree to split on before the 'cats' and 'dogs' are accounted for and that's because it takes the WHOLE vector to represent the sentence. But it really just depends on the embedding. As for why 345 the tree found that splitting your data up based on that decision is the 'best' first step AKA the two sets of those below 345 and above has most difference in terms of class.

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Comment: Hey Tylerr, another query. hope you would help. I tried to predict an another test statement using the above classification DT. But they donot classify it well. Ex-" i like sports" and decision tree states that it belong to class 1(denoting crime) rather than class 0. Why does this happen?  less number of training sentences? or some other reasons?

Comment: Few issues that are likely.
1: Your sentence is super short for document embeddings and may be better with word embedding rather than whole document (then average the word embeddings)
2: Your model has never seen sports
3: Your embeddings need to be trained on your corpus rather than pretrained networks from the library
4: You are using a decision tree which is not the best and should use boosted trees.